# qmake: Nested function call in .pro files

Tags: qt, qmake

Given the following code contained in a qmake project file:

```
         QWT_LIB_BINARY=/usr/lib/libqwt-qt4.so
         TEMP1 = $$basename(QWT_LIB_BINARY)
         TEMP2 = $$replace(TEMP1, .so, )
         QWT_LIB_NAME = $$replace(TEMP2, lib, )
         message(QWT library name = $$QWT_LIB_NAME)
```

Eliminates the path, the 'lib' prefix and the '.so' suffix of the string
contained in the QWT_LIB_BINARY variable. When compiling, the 'make' command
outputs the following line:

```
          Project MESSAGE: QWT library name = qwt-qt4
```

When the temporary variable assignations are eliminated, like this:

```
         QWT_LIB_BINARY=/usr/lib/libqwt-qt4.so
         QWT_LIB_NAME = $$replace($$replace($$basename(QWT_LIB_BINARY), .so, ), lib, )
         message(QWT library name = $$QWT_LIB_NAME)
```

The 'make' command outputs the message:

```
           Project MESSAGE: QWT library name =
```

Indicating that the last code is not working correctly. Is it possible to
nest function calls in '.pro' files in some other way, so it can work?

Comment: I'm looking at the same issue - and I'm gobsmacked that `qmake` even fails at functionality that trivial. Will migrate to `cmake` at the earliest occasion.